IntelliJ IDEA not detecting CORENLP dependencies
I am trying to follow this tutorial: https://medium.com/@varun85gupta/harnessing-sentiment-analysis-with-java-a-step-by-step-guide-using-nlp-f464398bb664
I have installed Maven, configured the POM to this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.simplestcodings</groupId>
    <artifactId>nlp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.6</version>
            <classifier>models</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>

and my Java class looks like this:
package com.simplestcodings;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class SentimentAnalysis {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Initialize the Stanford NLP pipeline
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP("application.properties");

        // Sample text for sentiment analysis
        String text = "Simplest codings is the best place to learn and grow. I am glad to be here.";

        // Perform sentiment analysis
        String sentiment = getSentiment(text, pipeline);

        // Display the result
        log.info("Text: {}, Sentiment: {}",text, sentiment);

        // Another Sample text for sentiment analysis
        text = "I hate this place. I am not coming back here again. I am very disappointed.";

        // Perform sentiment analysis
        sentiment = getSentiment(text, pipeline);

        // Display the result
        log.info("Text: {}, Sentiment: {}",text, sentiment);
    }

    private static String getSentiment(String text, StanfordCoreNLP pipeline) {
        // Create an Annotation object with the input text
        Annotation annotation = new Annotation(text);

        // Run all the NLP annotators on the text
        pipeline.annotate(annotation);

        // Extract the sentiment from the annotation
        CoreMap sentence = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class).get(0);
        String sentiment = sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentClass.class);

        return sentiment;
    }
}


But these are the errors I am recieving:
Errors
I have tried invalidating the cache, rebuilding the project and checking file versions which are:
JAVA: java version "22.0.1" 2024-04-16 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 22.0.1+8-16) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0.1+8-16, mixed mode, sharing) 
MAVEN: Apache Maven 3.9.6
I have also tried to setup the project in Amazon Coretto JDK 17, like the tutorial but still no luck
Please help.

Assuming the imports and Classes/Methods names are valid (and they seem to be valid in this case), this kind of behavior typically indicates that Maven Project's configuration was misinterpreted by IDEA or IDEA's caches got damaged/corrupted.
Try the following:

Close all instances of IDEA

Remove or rename projects and workspace folders (if present) found in the System Directory

Re-import the Project: Open -> Navigate to Project's directory -> Double-click the root pom.xml -> Open as Project


If the issue persists you can try renaming/removing the entire System Directory
If the issue persist still submit a YouTrack Issue or a Support Ticket.
